# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items error in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, viewmodel

I have a partial view that contains dropdown list that takes values from a table called Months, this partial view used in view called PSR

I passed object in controller:

```
public ActionResult PSR()
    {

        var PSRS = _context.PSRs.ToList();
        var months = _context.Months.ToList();

        var viewModel = new PSRViewModel
        {
            PSRs = PSRS,
            Months = months

        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Inside partial view:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.PSRViewModel

 <h5> Month </h5>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Month.month)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Month.month, new SelectList(Model.Months, "Id",     "month"), "--Select Month--", new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
```

And this inside PSR view:

```
@model List<Project.ViewModels.PSRViewModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "PSR";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Doctors/_AddPSR.cshtml", new      Project.ViewModels.PSRViewModel()) </div>
```

So why this error keep appearing when running the PSR view? even with passing object to that view

This is the ViewModel class code:

```
 namespace Project.ViewModels
{
public class PSRViewModel
{

    public PSR PSR { get; set; }
    public List<PSR> PSRs { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public List<Month> Months { get; set; }
    public Month Month { get; set; }
}
}
```

Should I put this in controller ?

```
var months = new List<Month> {

 };
```

**UPDATE:** 
Month model

```
namespace Project.Models
{
public class Month
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string month { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the PSRViewModel.Month.month? Can we see the Definition of this class?

Comment: Yes, I put it..

Comment: Feels like you want to loop through your model, calling @html.partial("VIEWNAME", model[i])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your primary view is incorrect, if you want to view only one PSRView model then change your @model and then pass it to your partial later.

Change your PSRView

```
@model Project.ViewModels.PSRViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "PSR";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Doctors/_AddPSR.cshtml", model)
```

For more than one PSRView

```
@model List<Project.ViewModels.PSRViewModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "PSR";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div>
@foreach(PSRViewModel m in model){
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Doctors/_AddPSR.cshtml", m)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this happens because though you create `PSRViewModel` you do not instantiate Months list. By default, it will be initialized with a null value. So, you could simply do this:

```
public class PSRViewModel
{
    public PSR PSR { get; set; }
    public List<PSR> PSRs { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public List<Month> Months { get; set; } = new List<Month>();
    public Month Month { get; set; }
}
```

But, of course, it won't help if you want to load your data from the database to this list

Comment: The error disappeared, but the list is empty as you mentioned.. Hmm is there another way to do this? .. thanks

Comment: You understand that the call to @Html.Partial in your view does not call the controller method?